# Delete columns in text files with specific string

Tags: r, string, bash, specification-pattern

I would like to delete collumns with a specific string "Gtype." from a .txt tab delimited file. I already have tried this command in R: `df <- df[, -grep("GType.", colnames(df))]` to do this task. However my matrix is too big (more than 13 GB), and R cannot deal with it. (Error: cannot allocate vector of size....)

My input file:

```
Log.NE122  Gtype.NE122  Log.NE144    Gtype.NE144
-0.33          AA          1.0           AB
```

My expected output:

```
   Log.NE122  Log.NE144  
    -0.33       1.0
```

I am wondering that it works in bash. If someone have other options....

Comment: Does "Gtype" appears only in first line?

Comment: Yes, I R it is a HEAD of table.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /Gtype/) a[i]; 
     else printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; print ""; next}
     {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (!(i in a)) printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; print "" }' file
Log.NE122 Log.NE144
-0.33     1.0
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I have an almost similar problem. My string would be like this `RT12-ABS-NSA` or like this `ADM_THO_CVL2000`. Yet, when I change the part of your script to look for that string, nothing is happening.

Do you have any clue on the why?

Comment: @AndyK: It is difficult to suggest anything without looking at your sample data and expected outcome. I suggest creating a question if possible with all the relevant details.

Comment: apologies, Anubhava. Your solution works. I've amended it for my purpose 
`awk -F";" 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /Gtype/) a[i]; 
     else printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; print ""; next}
     {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (!(i in a)) printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; print "" }'`

but it removes my semi-colon and give me space instead.

Comment: my question is here. Would you mind to have a look, please?  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134450/remove-columns-with-string-match-bash?

Comment: @anubhava , do you have to specify `FS` and `OFS` here?

Comment: Default FS and OFS are 1 or more of spaces or tabs. In this problem it appears from question that default values would work well

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using the 'data.table' package and assign the columns NULL:

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, colToDelete := NULL]
```

"data.table" tries to do most of its operations without having to make copies.  The way that you are doing it on `data.frame`s requires a copy to be made.

Comment: `setDT(df)` prevents even the copy of `data.frame` to `data.table` - by converting by reference :). `setDT(df)[, col_to_delete := NULL]`