# remove columns with string match bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm encountering the following issue.

I need to remove columns within a file that contain a specific string in the header. 
The semi-colon are acting as column limit

Examples below

```
file 1
ADM_THO_CVL2000,ZO,AT;BS-CCI-BAL,ARA,EL;BS-TLI-MS,ARA,BG; 
1;2;3;
4;5;6;


file 2
BS-CCI-BAL,ARA,EL;BS-TLI-MS,ARA,BG;ADM_THO_CVL2000,OZ,ES;BAG-AL,W,SE;
1;2;3;5;
4;5;6;7;
```

`ADM_THO_CVL2000` is the specific string I need to remove. The results , once string and the subsequent columns are removed, are below:

```
BS-CCI-BAL,ARA,EL;BS-TLI-MS,ARA,BG; 
2;3;
5;6;

BS-CCI-BAL,ARA,EL;BS-TLI-MS,ARA,BG;BAG-AL,W,SE;
1;2;5;
4;5;7;
```

I had a look on the internet.

`awk` can do the job that but the results I'm having, are not the one that I expect. I'm giving you the code below:

```
awk '
FNR==1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if ($i ~ str) {
          h=(h)?h FS $i:$i
          f=(f)?f FS i:i
        }
    print h
    nf=split(f,fA,FS);next
 }
 {
 for(i=1;i<=nf;i++)
       printf("%s%c",$fA[i], (i==nf)?ORS:FS)
}' str=ADM_THO_CVL2000, 'FS=;' filename.csv
```

I'm all ears for any of your suggestions.

Cheers

Comment: Oh well.  Seems like a school exercise.  Exactly same question asked a couple of hours back.

Comment: I could not find anything , Devnull :)

@ Ashkhan : Checking your answer.

Comment: Is all of your input 2 blocks from 1 file or is that intended to be 2 possible input files? It matters so be clear...

Comment: Hi Ed, 

These are 2 input files.

Comment: @Ashkan I've used anubhava's answer but I cannot use it for my string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some enhancements in my earlier solution. Since you could not resolve it I am posting my answer:

```
awk -F';' '/ADM_THO_CVL2000/{delete a; for (i=1; i<NF; i++) 
   if ($i ~ /ADM_THO_CVL2000/) a[i]; else printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; print $i; next} 
   {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if (!(i in a)) printf "%s%s", $i, OFS; print $i }' OFS=';' file

file 1
BS-CCI-BAL,ARA,EL;BS-TLI-MS,ARA,BG;
2;3;
5;6;    

file 2
BS-CCI-BAL,ARA,EL;BS-TLI-MS,ARA,BG;BAG-AL,W,SE;
1;2;5;
4;5;7;
```

Comment: Cheers @anubhava for that one. No, I could not figured that one by myself this time. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out for you.

Comment: You know, i feel dumb but really , I mean dumb , with how knowledgeable you and the other folks are. I just hope that I'm doing my amount of work by transmitting what you are teaching me here to other folks. 

Sorry for that minor ranting , just feeling the burden of the drudge when you are trying to deal with issues and way of doing you have not dealt with, before. 

Cheers again.

Comment: No worries Andy. Just a suggestion that posting you attempt (even if it is not working) will make your question more popular in the sense that it will attract more answers.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. That is really kind of you. Indeed, let me post what I put. That may help other people.